# (ExtJS) Set row height for fieldset table

Tags: css, extjs

This seems like it would be a simple solution, but I cannot figure out how to set the row height of my fieldset table. Playing with the CSS didn't seem to do anything either.

```
xtype: 'fieldset',
title: 'Fieldset',
layout: {
    type: 'table',
    columns: 2,
    cellCls: 'myFormTblCell'
},
margin: '5 5 5 5',
items: [{
    xtype: 'label',
    text: 'lable 1',
    cls: 'myLabel'
},{
    xtype: 'displayfield',
    name: 'displayfield 1',
    cls: 'myText'
},{
    xtype: 'label',
    text: 'lable 2',
    cls: 'myLabel'
},{
    xtype: 'displayfield',
    name: 'displayfield 2',
    cls: 'myText'
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use ExtJS version 4.2.2, in which you would do the following

In your layout config...

```
layout: {
    type: 'table',
    columns: 2,
    trAttrs: { height: 50 },
    cellCls: 'myFormTblCell'
},
```

[Documentation on ExtJS table layout](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Table)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehxos3r5/)